# Was Satyabhama jealous of other wives of Krishna?

Tags: krishna, satyabhama

In the "Prabhandam Parijatapaharanam" book, the poet *Nandi Thimmana* wrote that Satyabhama kicked Lord Krishna with her left leg because of her jealousy that Lord Krishna gave a flower *Parijata Pushpam* to his other wife Rukmini.

Is there any truth in this story or is it just a poetic imagination?

Answer (score 3):

No, Satyabhama was not jealous with other wives of Kirshna. But she considered herself to be more important than other wives of kirshna. Satyabhama thought that she is the only one who can make Krishna happy and not any other.

So, Satyabhama was not jealous with other wives, but she always wanted Krishna to give more importance to her than any other wives. When krishna spent some time with others, she didn't like it and became angry. Some consider this as jealousy.

I read this from "Krishna Avatar" part 5,6,7,8 by Kanaiyalal Munshi (in Gujarati).

Answer (score 3):

I would say Satyabhama kicking Shri Krishna is just poetic imagination. Satyabhma was proud of her beauty, chastity and love for Krishna. She always believed Shri Krishna loved her more. So when she heard from her maids that Shri Krishna had given the magnificent *parijata* flower to Rukmani, she became jealous and arrogant:

> *rūpayauvanasampannā svasaubhāgyena garvitā
>
>   abhimnavatī devī śrutvaiverṣyāvaśaṃ gatā*  [HP - 2.65.50]
>
> **Meaning**
>   The goddess endowed with beauty and youth, proud for her good fortune, became envious after hearing this.

After Shri Krishna went to Satyabhama leaving the company of Narada and Rukmani and talked with her, she said:

> *madīyastvamiti hyāsīnmama nityaṃ manaḥ prabho
>
>   adya sādhāraṇaṃ snehaṃ tvayi tāvadgatāsmyaham* [HP - 2.66.47]
>
> **Meaning**
>   Oh lord, I had always thought you to be mine. But today I know that your love for me is ordinary.

So she showed haughtiness, but did not kick Shri Krishna. Saints and poets sometimes just spice up things a bit more out of love and mischief.

Comment: What does HP stand for?  Is it the Harivamsa?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan yes, Harivamsa Purana

Answer (score 3):

Nope,everyone claims are her jealous without reading scriptures.

First of all if mata Satyabhama had problem with Krishna spending time with others why she didn't had problem with Sri krishna marriage ?

Satyabhama never was jealous nor had any issue with sisters like co-wives. Infact they cared each other like own sisters.

Harivamsa mentions:
With all their desires satisfied by lord Narayana, the women did not feel jealous ( about each other ) even though their mind and eyes were devoted to same one 2-88-20

Yadavabhyudaya mentions :

"Even Narada could not stage any of his kalahas to create misunderstanding among his wives"

Their bond is unbreakable then how can Satya amma be jealous of her own self ( Sri Krishna wives soul is same they're same sita) .

Parijat leela never mentioned Satyabhama mata as jealous. Satyabhama kicking Sri Krishna was a fictional imagination of a poet in 15th century.

Really reason behind parijat haran

Yadavabhyudaya chapter in short :

In short it was Sri Krishna who has willed to take the tree , may be, to show the power of His maya which made Indra forget the great help rendered by Krishna and fight with him over the tree. He put words in the mouth of Sathyabhama to achieve this end by saying that she looked as though she wanted to take the tree and plant it in her garden

So it was Sri Krishna not Mata Satyabhama and mata Satyabhama didn't wanted parijat nor she was jealous of Rukmini and asked Parijat.
Gopala champu mentions:

Deva-ksma-pati-sac-chala-pujita-deva-ksmaruha-hrti-vanchacita

" O Lord who was then worshipped by the devatas and bramhanas ,o lord then who desired to take a parijat tree from devatas
~Text 9

Vishnu puran Padma puran describes Satyabhama asked Parijat to don't hurt their pride and she was right, she didn't desired tree in actual. After leela Satyabhama Krishna refused to take parijat but the Indra deva requested them to take.

Vishnu puran :

Satyabhámá seeing Indra disarmed, and his elephant disabled by Garud́a, and the deity himself about to retreat, said to him, "King of the triple sphere, it ill becomes the husband of Śachí to run away. Ornamented with Párijáta garlands, she will approach you. Of what use is the sovereignty of heaven, embellished with the Párijáta tree, no longer beholding Śachí meet you with affection as of yore? Nay, Śakra, fly not; you must not suffer shame: here, take the Párijáta tree; let the gods be no longer annoyed. Sachs, inflated with pride of her husband, has not welcomed me to her dwelling with respectful presents. As a woman, I am light of purpose, and am anxious for my husband's fame; therefore have I instigated, Śakra, this contest with you. But I do not want the Párijáta tree, nor do I wish to take that which is another's property. Śachí is proud of her beauty. What woman is not proud of her husband?" Thus spoken to by Satyabhámá, the king of the gods turned back, and said to her, "Desist, wrathful dame, from afflicting your friend by further reproaches. I am not ashamed of being vanquished by him who is the author of the creation, preservation, and destruction of the world; who is the substance of all things; in whom, without beginning or middle, the universe is comprised; and from whom, and by whom, identical with all things, it proceeds, and will cease to be. What disgrace is it, O goddess, to any one to be discomfited by him who is the cause of creation, continuance, and dissolution? His form is the parent of all worlds, though infinitely subtle, and known to those only by whom all that may be known is known. Who is able to overcome the unborn, unconstituted, eternal lord, who has willed to become a mortal for the good of the.......